# UITableView reloadSection cause missing displayed cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm using Realm Notification to update my table with insert, modifications, and deletions.

```
self.results = realm.objects(PostObject.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: false)

notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
        switch changes {
        case .initial:

            tableView.reloadData()

            break
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):

            tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(deletions), with: .automatic)
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(insertions), with: .automatic)
            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(modifications), with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()

            tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            break
        case .error(let error):

            fatalError("\(error)")

            break
        }
}
```

At the first update the table displays correctly. The second time the update is called, the tableview starts losing cells. Like this:

[image: missing cell]

In this example the deletions and modifications were empty, only the insertions array was full of indexes. I see that this problem is also caused when I scroll the tableview during an update.

Comment: Have you checked a thread on which a callback is working? If it is not on the main thread, you can dispatch it to the main queue with dispatch_async

Comment: Yes, I've dispatch it to the main queue like this: DispatchQueue.main.async { /* begin - insert - end */ }. I see that the table does not have this problems if is not scrolling during the update.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted jumps out as being incorrect. A full Xcode project demonstrating the issue might either 1) help you find out what you're doing incorrectly or 2) help Realm folks (hi!) identify a bug in Realm.

Comment: Sound really strange but now, after I remove the html decode function I was using inside 'cellForRowAtIndex', the table works perfectly. I also see that now it perform the update only when the user stop scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for missing cells while using a custom subclass of a `UITableViewCell` is forgetting to call `super.prepareForReuse()`.

Apple states at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse:

> If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass
>   implementation.

Always be sure to call super:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    // your code follows
}
```